# MVC4 - Why is my URL rewrite preventing me from accessing the ID in a custom AuthoriseAttribute

Tags: .net, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-attributes

I am currently writing an Authorisation filter in MVC4, it has the default URL rewrite

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

And with the above route I have a custom authorise attribute which starts like this

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    String Value = httpContext.Request["id"];
```

however the id isn't coming through.

When I take the route away above it does.

Is there anyway I can have the route AND the id in the authorise attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in my solution, I managed to get the information I needed out of the RouteData in the RequestContext -

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        String Value = httpContext.Request["id"];
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value))
            Value = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] as String;
```